# for finding limit points of trigonometric function

Tags: real-analysis

How to find limit point of $\sin(1/n)$. Please give full description. Tell me by graph or any other method. I have been told its lp is 0 but according to me it should be closed interval $-1$ to $1$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please update your question with how you got $[-1,1].$

Comment: do you mean $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$?

Comment: Since its range is {-1,1} and its every point contain infinite terms of sequence

Answer (score 2):

Given $\epsilon>0$,

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sin (1/n)=0$$

$$\implies $$
for $n $ great enough
$$\sin (1/n)\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$$

thus the only limit point is zero.

Answer (score 1):

When $n \to \infty $ then  $ \frac{1}{n}  \to 0$, so $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin\left(\frac{1}n\right) = \sin(0)=0.$$